# Fluxcd multiple repo and cluster without helm

Tags: multiple-repositories, fluxcd

How to handle multiple repository and clusters in Fluxcd v2 without using helm repository

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

fluxed provide an example repo, [flux2-multi-tenancy](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux2-multi-tenancy)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30058393)

Answer (score 0):

1. one cluster multiple git repos
   deploy multiple GitRepositories and multiple fluxcd
   Kustomization [link](https://fluxcd.io/flux/guides/repository-structure/)
2. for the multiple clusters using same repo. have dedicated folders on the repo for each cluster, and you can place [fluxcd
   Kustomization](https://fluxcd.io/flux/components/kustomize/kustomization/) in each which will have pointers to kustomize.config.k8s.io/Kustomization on the same repo